# Facebook Application without Popup and SSL

Tags: php, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing facebook app using javascript SDK.

Is there any possibility to run facebook app without SSL with HTTPS URL but block popup window by browser.

My facebook app works fine in mozzila browser but in Google chrome its cant run because my google chrome browser block popup window.

so facebook authentication failed so its cant work ahead and stopped there. Is there any alternative way to solve it.

Your help appreciate me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/secure-browsing-by-default/10151590414803920

It's no longer possible to not use HTTPS on Facebook (which is a good thing!).

You cannot do anything against blocked pop-ups except telling the user that there is a pop-up that might be blocked.

Comment: Thanks your answer help me to find solution.